# Online tool to convert JSON to C# object format

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I'm looking for a quick and simple way to convert large JSON objects in a text file to C# object notation for a company project. I would prefer an online solution (similar to jsbeautifier.org) that would take my code, parse it, and return a C# formatted object.

Are there any tools (preferably online) that will do this? I'm hoping not to do this by hand, but writing a script might take time that I don't have right now. (I'm not too well-versed with C# library calls.)

Thank you!

Comment: You want an anonymous object? Difficult to pass around your code. ... or do you want generated class definitions?

Comment: Whoops, should have specified - I'd like to convert a JSON string into a C# object string. I don't need the actual object - just its string, as if I called object.ToString(). Really, I need to convert code in one language to code in a different language.

Comment: I updated the post, have a look.

Comment: For those who stumble across this question with the same need (yaay, SO :-| ) there's a nice tool here that works well. http://json2csharp.com/ This does schema, but not data.

Comment: Have a look at [QuickType.io](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Answer (score 7):

I think following link will help.

[Generate c# classes from json](http://json2csharp.com/)

Actually it uses the same project which achitaka-san said in his post. You can create a simple WebService in any host and use it.

Answer (score 5):

This application generates C# classes from a sample JSON text, so you can use strongly typed programming with JSON.

http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com

This is not online, but you just download an EXE, paste your JSON and get a c# class - taht's it.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to generate this with the data it contains? I mean like a complete C# object that also contains the data from the JSON string.